# How to resolve ' syntaxError Unexpected token, expected "}" '

Tags: react-native

I'm programming an app using react native. This is my first time doing it. I'm acquainted with *Classes* and *functions* as `contruct`.

Until now everything was working, but now for some reason the code doesn't compile and throw this error

> SyntaxError: /ggProject/App.js: Unexpected token, expected "}"
>   (119:23)

I've been a while trying to figure it out what's wrong, but I cant find the error. The line `119:23` is in the first `"{"` of the Constructor.

```
class Cartas extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    state = {
        carta: 0
    };
}
nextCard = () => {
    var y = this.state.carta + 1;
    this.setState({carta: y })
    if(this.state.carta === 3) {Alert.alert('se activaron')}
}

displayCarta() {
    if(this.state.carta <= 2){
        if (this.state.carta%4 == 0) {
            return <CTodos players={this.props.players} changePage={this.props.changePage} next={this.nextCard}/>
        } else if (this.state.carta%4 == 1) {
            return <CSecuencia changePage={this.props.changePage} next={this.nextCard} />
        } else if (this.state.carta%4 == 2) {
            return <CPregunta  changePage={this.props.changePage} next={this.nextCard} />
        }
    }else {
        if (this.state.carta%4 == 0) {
            return <CTodos players={this.props.players} changePage={this.props.changePage} next={this.nextCard}/>
        } else if (this.state.carta%4 == 1) {
            return <CSecuencia changePage={this.props.changePage} next={this.nextCard} />
        } else if (this.state.carta%4 == 2) {
            return <CPregunta  changePage={this.props.changePage} next={this.nextCard} />
        }else if (this.state.carta%4 == 3) {
           return <CReto  changePage={this.props.changePage} next={this.nextCard} />
       }
    }
}
render() {
    return (
            this.displayCarta()
    )
}
}
```

Comment: You really need to show more code than that.

Comment: That is the entire Class , what more do you need? :)

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the snippet provided you have not added the closing `}` which is a syntax error. It should look like the following:

```
class Cartas extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        carta: 0
      };
  }
}
```

Adding a lint tool to your project along with a relational text editor plugin will help you pick up these syntax errors in real time.

Comment: Hi, yes I close the class below, the whole class is so much bigger , I just  shared the fragment where the  code  shows me that is the syntaxError. this is weird for me because I used the same struct  for anothers Classes , and always works .The whole classes of the code are equal . I'm using Expo , maybe the error is there , when I update the code with some simple change , expo doesn't react and I have to turn on again the server and the expo app. I didn't jnow about the "lint tools" I will search about that.Thank you

Comment: Can you show me the block of code ending at line 119 in your file please?

Comment: i did just update the code. there is the entire Class

Comment: what does your export look like?

Comment: sorry but  what do you mean? When I try to run my code this is what the console shows me
 "[22:10:38] SyntaxError: /home/guillermo/ggProject/App.js: Unexpected token, expected "}" (119:23)
[22:10:38] 
[22:10:38]   117 | 
[22:10:38]   118 | class Cartas extends Component {
[22:10:38] > 119 |     constructor(props) {
[22:10:38]       |                        ^
[22:10:38]   120 |         super(props);
[22:10:38]   121 |         this.state = {
[22:10:38]   122 |             carta: 0,
"

Answer (score -1):

I think your component should like this

```
class Cartas extends Component
    state = {
        carta: 0
    }
}
```

Pointers

1. You don't use constructors for initialization (at least they don't specify doing so in the docs)
2. You can't set the state via `this`. You can set the state initially like I did above and then beyond that it can only be set using the `setState()` function

Comment: There is nothing wrong with calling constructor and setting state in the body. OP's code is not incorrect and it's perfectly fine to write it how he has. What you've written is just an es6 way of writing a similar thing. You also have provided code with a syntax error.

Comment: I'm new using react native, thank you both to your corrections. I been using the same struct of  classes and constructor in anothers classes and that worked to me.that's why this error looks weird to me.I'm using Expo to prove my code in an android device.maybe the error is related with it. Now expo stop working after shows me this sintax error , if I cant something of the code and I update,expo doesn't response and the console shows me this "Building JavaScript bundle [===============================================] 99%"I have to get down the server and turn it on again, to see some change.